# Setting font size or centering messes up interline space

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fontsize

I have a title spread on three lines:

```
\begin{center}
{\textbf{MY \\BEAUTIFUL \\TITLE}}
\end{center}
```

[image]

but as soon as I want to change the font size, it messes up the interline space:

```
\begin{center}
{\Huge\textbf{MY \\BEAUTIFUL \\TITLE}}
\end{center}
```

[image]

(notice the different space between the first and second line, and the second and third line).

Now if I remove the center environment and leave the Huge command, the interline is fine but I get a blank character before my first word:

```
{\Huge\textbf{MY \\BEAUTIFUL \\TITLE}}
```

[image]

So it seems like a weird interaction between the center environment and the font command? I’ve been trying to fix this for 3 hours now. What am I missing?

Comment: @c.p. no same output as in screenshot 2

Comment: You should  always include an end of paragraph in the size change put a blank line or `\par` before `}}` or simpler remove the outer `{...}` which are doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 \begin{center} {\Huge\textbf{MY \\BEAUTIFUL \\TITLE}\par} \end{center}
```

Comment: This works, but why do I have to do this by hand? Isn’t this a basic task for LaTex? Is it because of the line breaks inside my title? And what if I want to increase the interline space after that? Do I have to just "try" with different values until I’m happy?

Comment: this does not correct the cause of the error, the missing `\par`

Comment: @Sulli it does it automatically if `\par` is there, as David said